# When I use .get_text() for BeautifulSoup, nothing shows up

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am unable to parse the Yelp review rating.

I made a quick video of the problem. 
https://streamable.com/42oj4

```
bs = soup(page_html, "html.parser")


yelp_containers = bs.findAll("div", {"class": "lemon--div__373c0__1mboc searchResult__373c0__1yggB border-color--default__373c0__2xHhl"})
print(len(yelp_containers))
print(yelp_containers[1].text)


restaurant_title = yelp_containers[1].find("div", {"class": "lemon--div__373c0__1mboc businessName__373c0__1fTgn border-color--default__373c0__2xHhl"}).get_text()
print("restaurant_title: ", restaurant_title)

restaurant_address = yelp_containers[1].find("address", {"class": 'lemon--address__373c0__2sPac'}).get_text()
print("restaurant_address: " , restaurant_address)

restaurant_numReview = yelp_containers[1].find("span", {"class": "lemon--span__373c0__3997G text__373c0__2pB8f reviewCount__373c0__2r4xT text-color--mid__373c0__3G312 text-align--left__373c0__2pnx_"}).get_text()
print("restaurant_numReview: ", restaurant_numReview)

restaurant_starCount = yelp_containers[1].find("div", {"class": "lemon--div__373c0__1mboc i-stars__373c0__30xVZ i-stars--regular-4__373c0__2R5IO border-color--default__373c0__2oFDT overflow--hidden__373c0__8Jq2I"}).get_text()
print("restaurant_starCount: ", restaurant_starCount)
```

I expect to get "4 star rating", but I get nothing.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You can/should turn blocks of code into *code blocks*, try putting three "back-ticks" `\`\`\`` in a line of their own before and after the code.

Comment: Can you share URL of the yelp page?

Comment: @AndrejKesely https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Restaurants&find_loc=San%20Francisco%2C%20CA

In addition, here is the entire code: https://pastebin.com/VHiY4qqa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To **scrape** star count, you could use this code:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

try: #python3
    from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
except: #python2
    from urllib2 import urlopen as uReq


my_url = 'https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Restaurants&find_loc=San%20Francisco%2C%20CA'

#opening connection and grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
bs = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

rows = []
for h3 in bs.select('h3'):
    title = h3.get_text(strip=True)
    if not re.findall(r'^\d+\.', title):
        continue
    address = h3.find_next(class_=re.compile(r'secondaryAttributes')).get_text(separator=' ', strip=True)
    _, telephone, address = re.split(r'(\(\d+\) \d+-\d+)\s*', address)
    num_reviews = re.findall(r'\d+', h3.find_next(class_=re.compile(r'reviewCount')).text)[0]
    star_count = re.findall(r'\d+.?\d*', h3.find_next(lambda t: t.name=='div' and 'aria-label' in t.attrs)['aria-label'])[0]

    rows.append([title, address, telephone, num_reviews, star_count])

print('{: ^40}{: ^60}{: ^20}{: ^15}{: ^10}'.format('Title', 'Address', 'Telephone', 'Num. reviews', 'Star Count'))
for row in rows:
    print('{: <40}{: <60}{: ^20}{: ^15}{: ^10}'.format(*row))
```

Prints:

```
                 Title                                            Address                                Telephone       Num. reviews  Star Count
1.Fog Harbor Fish House                 Pier 39 Fisherman's Wharf                                      (415) 421-2442        5476          4     
2.Marufuku Ramen SF                     Located in Japan Center Lower Pacific Heights                  (415) 872-9786        2345         4.5    
3.The House                             1230 Grant Ave North Beach/Telegraph Hill                      (415) 986-8612        4634         4.5    
4.Zazie                                 941 Cole St Cole Valley                                        (415) 564-5332        4256          4     
5.Farmhouse Kitchen Thai Cuisine        710 Florida St Mission                                         (415) 814-2920        1996          4     
6.Burma Superstar                       309 Clement St Inner Richmond                                  (415) 387-2147        6605          4     
7.Pier Market Seafood Restaurant        Pier 39 Fisherman's Wharf                                      (415) 989-7437        1879          4     
8.Suppenküche                           525 Laguna St Hayes Valley                                     (415) 830-4716        3080          4     
9.um.ma                                 1220 9th Ave Inner Sunset                                      (415) 566-5777         54           4     
10.Surisan                              505 Beach St Fisherman's Wharf                                 (415) 771-8449        1508         4.5    
11.The New Spot On Polk                 2401 Polk St Russian Hill                                      (415) 913-7775         532         4.5    
12.San Tung                             1031 Irving St Inner Sunset                                    (415) 242-0828        6596          4     
13.Daeho Kalbijjim & Beef Soup          1620 Post St Japantown                                         (415) 563-1388         330         4.5    
14.Kitchen Story                        3499 16th St Castro                                            (415) 525-4905        3081          4     
15.Liholiho Yacht Club                  871 Sutter St Lower Nob Hill                                   (415) 440-5446        2186         4.5    
16.The Codmother Fish & Chips           496 Beach St Fisherman's Wharf                                 (415) 606-9349        2892         4.5    
17.Beretta                              1199 Valencia St Mission                                       (415) 695-1199        3495          4     
18.Loló                                 974 Valencia St Mission                                        (415) 643-5656        2061          4     
19.Noosh                                2001 Fillmore St Lower Pacific Heights                         (415) 231-5985         161          4     
20.Hog Island Oyster Co                 Located in Ferry Building Marketplace Embarcadero              (415) 391-7117        5718         4.5    
21.Z & Y Restaurant                     655 Jackson St Chinatown                                       (415) 981-8988        1570         3.5    
22.The Front Porch                      65 29th St Bernal Heights                                      (415) 695-7800        2708          4     
23.Delarosa                             2175 Chestnut St Marina/Cow Hollow                             (415) 673-7100        1446          4     
24.Brenda’s French Soul Food            652 Polk St Tenderloin                                         (415) 345-8100        10586         4     
25.Dumpling Kitchen                     1935 Taraval St Parkside                                       (415) 682-8938        1419          4     
26.Scoma’s Restaurant                   1965 Al Scoma Way Fisherman's Wharf                            (415) 771-4383        3548          4     
27.Causwells                            2346 Chestnut St Marina/Cow Hollow                             (415) 447-6081         696          4     
28.Mr Szechuan                          890 Taraval St Parkside                                        (415) 753-8788         128         4.5    
29.Dumpling Time                        11 Division St                                                 (415) 525-4797        1494          4     
30.Tuba Authentic Turkish Restaurant    1007 Guerrero St Mission                                       (415) 826-8822         983         4.5
```